# How to set the expiration of items in idempotent camel hazelcast repository?

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

I'm using camel-hazelcast for an idempotent repository for reading files.

How can I set the expiry of items in the repo? Are there camel config options or should I be looking at configuring hz directly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:
* set a TTL on the put: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#put-K-V-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

- set an eviction policy on the map: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.6/manual/html-single/index.html#map-eviction

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks. What's the best way to get a handle on the repo so that i can set it? HazelcastInstance hzi = (HazelcastInstance) e.getContext().getRegistry().lookupByName("hzi"); and then set like that? I guess this bit is Camel specific